# Moq - Using VerifySet to check number of times called

Tags: c#, moq

I am trying to use VerifySet with Moq to check the number of times a setter on a collaborating Object is being called. But when I put in the Times portion of the call I get an error that the assignment operator is not valid in an expression tree.

```
mockTimer.VerifySet(timer => timer.Prop = value); //Works fine
mockTimer.VerifySet(timer => timer.Prop = value, Times.Once); //Compile Error
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to call the function `Times.Once()`:

```
mockTimer.VerifySet(timer => timer.Prop = value, Times.Once());
```